# Is it possible to set only owner password while using setEncryption method in iText?

Tags: java, pdf, encryption, itext, itextpdf

Is it possible to set owner password as some value and user password as null or empty while using set encryption method of PdfWriter class?

I tried using code something like this

```
 String OWNER = "test";
 PdfWriter.setEncryption(null,OWNER.getBytes(),
                        PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
```

I am able to open PDF generated with this code without entering any password.
BUT when I try to open it for editing with Adobe Acrobat, it opens the document in view mode and throws an error "This is secured document. Editing is not permitted."
Screenshot of error: http://dropbox.com/s/1ef551o1z0n9ug1/editerror.jpg

Any idea why this must be occurring? Am I doing something wrong?

On an additional note,

I have generated this new document with

```
PdfWriter.setEncryption("test1".getBytes(),"test".getBytes(), 
                        PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
```

Link: http://dropbox.com/s/8jeia7ezervrz18/Test_Success.pdf

I am able to view it after entering password as "test1" and able to edit it with password "test". I am not sure what exactly is going wrong when I pass USER as null in earlier case.

I am using following set of jars in my project

- itext-2.1.7.jar
- bcmail-jdk14.jar
- bcprov-jdk14.jar

Comment: If you secure a document, making sure it can only be printed (not granting any permissions to edit it), you shouldn't expect being able to edit it without providing the owner password. That's the whole idea of securing the document, isn't it?

Comment: Correct. That's what my requirement is. I just want to set edit password and not view password for the pdf being generated.

Comment: So what *is* the issue?

Comment: I believe that I am setting the correct password using OWNER param in above code snippet. But when I open PDF for editing, the adobe acrobat doesn't ask me for edit password. It throws an error instead.

Comment: Hi @BrunoLowagie, here is the link to PDF: https://www.dropbox.com/s/40njtm4scjy2rwi/Test.pdf

Comment: Which owner password did you use? It opens perfectly in Acrobat, without any error, but it goes without saying that I can't edit it without having the owner password.

Comment: Hi @BrunoLowagie, I am able to edit it too. I am facing issues with editing it. The password for the pdf is "test". Please check if you are able to edit it.

I have updated the other details in the question itself. Please take a look.

Comment: I've opened the document with Acrobat 9 and had no problem editing it: http://itextpdf.org/documents/Test.pdf I have Acrobat XI on a computer at my other office. I could check there, but... I don't see any problem with the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static String user = "";
    private static String admin = "ADMIN";      
writer.setEncryption(admin.getBytes(), user.getBytes(),
                PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
```

By using the above approach you can set admin password. There might be some problem in your classpath setting. Use `Mavel` on `Gardle` for dependencies

Comment: If `user` is `null`, the `user.getBytes()` should throw a `NullPointerException`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Exactly. It throws null pointer exception. Also, you have swapped the positions of user and admin parameters.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I am a novice sir. I am sorry to say I totally missed out about null pointer. But I feel glad as I got a comment from the creator of iText/Lowagie on my answer. I feel damn lucky today :)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I have tried to pass a empty string instead of null. It's working also

Comment: @Debaprasad--- Please correct your answer as pointed by Technocrat above that you have swapped the positions of user and admin parameters. This might be confusing to lots of guys who refer this...